# What is the difference between Azure AAD App ObjectId and ApplicationId?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

What is the difference between AzureAAD App ObjectId and ApplicationId, is there a specific reason that both are exposed to users? Is there a use case where ObjectId is definitely required over ApplicationId?

Comment: Take a look I hope you would get your proper idea about. Still if you have any question feel free to ask here in comment.

Comment: Thanks, this also clarifies my question on difference btw service principal and aad app!

Comment: Glad to hear, be connected and happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Application Id**

`ApplicationId` will be same for single application object that represents this application as well as it will be same for all service principals created for this application.

**Object Id**

`ObjectId` will be a unique value for application object and each of the service principal. This uniquely identifies the object in Azure AD. It's a property that you will find with all Azure AD objects, like even a user, group or anything else with Azure AD

1. **Is there a specific reason that both are exposed to users?**
2. **Is there a use case where ObjectId is definitely required over ApplicationId?**

Yeah there are many reason of that. Let's say, You need to know about your [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#application-and-service-principal-relationship) of your application using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-beta). You cannot call it directly.

For that you need to have  `resourceId` in the response, it is the `object id` of the target resource (service principal) for which the assignment was made.

Then call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/, the `appId` in the response is the `application id` of the AD App.

Then call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications, the `appId` in the response is the same with the `appId` retuned by GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/. Then you can match them.

This is why you need to expose `ApplicationId` and `ObjectId`. Like this there are many reason when you need those ID.

You could also refer mentioned resource to have some more idea about your queries [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)

If you still have any question feel free to ask here in comment. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for the one person (one email) to have different objectIds?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: The answer is not clear. "you cannot call it directly", call what directly?

Comment: `object Id` cannot be called directly, for getting each registered appliciation information we must need to use `Application (client) ID`. Hope this will resolve your confusion. Still if you have any more concern feel free le me know. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

An app registration in Azure AD results in an *Application* object. All objects in Azure AD have an object ID. When you making an API request to address a specific *Application* object, you would use the object ID:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/applications/{object-id}?api-version=1.6
```

An *Application* object's object ID is only relevant in the same tenant where the app is registered, and is only ever used to identify that object.

An *Application* objects's `appId` attribute is used used across tenants, and on more than one object type. There are two primary uses:

1. To identify the app in various sign-in and token flows (e.g. `client_id` in OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect).
2. To uniquely identify the backing *Application* object of a *ServicePrincipal* object. (Think of the *ServicePrincipal* object as the "instance" of the app in a given Azure AD tenant.)